# Colorbar scaling in ImageGrid

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

Why is the following behaviour happening to my colorbars.. and how do I get it to behave "normal"?

```
x_array = np.random.rand(5, 15, 10)
x_array = np.array([np.random.randint(1,20) * x for x in x_array])
minmax_array = [-2, 2]
f = plt.figure()
ag = axes_grid.ImageGrid(f, rect=(1, 1, 0), nrows_ncols=(1,5), cbar_mode='each',
                         cbar_pad=0.05, axes_pad=0.5)
for j in range(5):
    x_temp = x_array[j, :, :]
    im = ag[j].imshow(x_temp)
    ag.cbar_axes[j].colorbar(im)
    ag.cbar_axes[j].set_yticks(minmax_array)
```

The result of this is shown below

[image]

As you can see, since I supply colorbar range outside of the values of the arrays.. I get this weird scaling of the colorbar.

But why cant it scale

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because vmin and vmax have not been set in imshow. If we execute the following code

```
x_array = np.random.rand(5, 15, 10)
x_array = np.array([np.random.randint(1,20) * x for x in x_array])
minmax_array = [-2, 2]
f = plt.figure()
ag = axes_grid.ImageGrid(f, rect=(1, 1, 0), nrows_ncols=(1,5), cbar_mode='each',
                         cbar_pad=0.05, axes_pad=0.5)
for j in range(5):
    x_temp = x_array[j, :, :]
    im = ag[j].imshow(x_temp, vmin=minmax_array)
    ag.cbar_axes[j].colorbar(im)
    ag.cbar_axes[j].set_yticks(minmax_array)
```

Note that "if vmin is a length2 sequence, interpret it as (vmin, vmax) which is used to support setp"[image]